# Java NetBeans Form Creator

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a C# .NET developer and I always use Visual Studio to create my applications. Now I am studying Java with the netbeans IDE and I have no clue of how to create a Form Application?

I have used Jform etc. But this is just annoying. I was trying for 3 hours just to relocate a button while resizing my window.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this easier?

Comment: Well you once started with C#/Winforms and you get that, so yust hang on and try to play with it, and it will be easy too. We can't do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, IMHO, creating GUI applications in Swing is a pain, especially coming from .NET.

Whenever I need to create Swing apps I find it easier to just hand code it. Although it involves much more work than in .NET, and also has a pretty steep learning curve, I find I have more control over my code that way.

BTW, once you get the hang of how things work in Swing, hand coding is pretty manageable.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'll check out the hand coding! Thanks!